# Ways to Digitally Sign data

Tags: cryptography, digital-signature

I have been researching on Digital Signatures for some time. First, I came across the PKCS standards, which involves treating any data or file as binary content and signing/encrypting the same.

Recently, I have come to know about other ways such as:

1) W3C XML Signature: which uses XML to sign any content on the internet (XML or not)

2) PDF Signatures: the ISO formats specify the mechanism for adding Digital Signatures to pdf files which can be read by pdf readers.

What other standards/techniques exist for digitally signing data programmatically?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that, for computer based algorithms, the data is always treated as binary data in the end. Currently the question is focusing on container formats hopefully intentionally.

Comment: @owlstead XML signing is to some extent different, as it performs text-based transformations before the data is signed. Of course the binary remains the binary, but in XMLDSig you can have one signature from multiple different XML "text".

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp Yeah, I know. It is different in the sense that you don't directly use the given data but tranform it first. I've written some code to perform WS-Security on top of XML digsig (as I didn't trust the default Sun and Apache implementations - not without reason as it turned out).

Answer (score 3):

PKCS#7 which you have mentioned.

CMS is an extension / successor to PKCS#7

Older MS Office binary formats contained their own signing mechanisms (similar to the ones in PDF). Newer MS Office XML-based format and OpenOffice format use XMLDSig.

OpenPGP signing (uses OpenPGP keypairs, not X.509 certificates).

PKWare supports signing of ZIP archives, and they let one freely verify those signatures (however, they don't offer a license to sign ZIPs yourself - only using their SecureZIP application).

Then there exist specification for signing PNG images: ftp://ftp.simplesystems.org/pub/png/documents/signatures/index.html

Maybe there exist other, less wide-spread formats which also have signatures, but that's all I can remember at the moment.